# Error in ClickOnce installation

Tags: wpf, deployment, clickonce

I am doing a ClickOnce deployment, and I am getting the following error:

---

```
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [02/06/2011 22:15:29] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (RefDefValidation)
        - Reference in the manifest does not match the identity of the downloaded assembly WPFAutoCompleteTextbox.exe.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
```

---

Does this mean that WPFAutoCompleteTextbox.exe is not usable?

This is my first ClickOnce deployment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [InvalidDeploymentException error when deploying .NET Application.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248314/invaliddeploymentexception-error-when-deploying-net-application)

Comment: hi djacobson, thanks for the link.  How to sign it with the same cert?  Its my first deployment so need some help.  Can you point me to any tutorials?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you make any changes to the files after they were deployed?  Editing deployed ClickOnce applications invalidates the manifest.

If I remember rightly, this can be fixed by opening the application and deployment manifests with mageui.exe - you need to associate the deployment manifest with the application manifest and sign it (even if the manifest wasn't signed in the first place, mage will make you sign it when editing it)

Comment: Hi TabbyCool thanks for your reply.  I have not made any changes to the files after they were deployed.  I just click on the setup.exe and after it starts extracting, it just stops with this error. I will try that with mageui.exe, and see what happens.

Comment: Hi TabbyCool, I tried to open with MageUI but no luck, now its not even starting the install and getting an error in the start!

Comment: Have you tried deploying the ClickOnce application again?  If there's a problem with the application or deployment manifest it's probably best to deploy it again and see if you still get the same problem.

Comment: Yes sure I did. So I published the app in a folder on my local drive, then opened the manifest with mage.exe, saved it, and then moved all the files in this folder to my server online.  Isn't it the correct way?

Comment: The first time you deployed it did you deploy it locally or directly to the server?  It's simpler to deploy straight to the server then you don't need to alter the manifests at all, you're less likely to run into problems that way.

Comment: I tried to deploy directly to the server, but it was asking me for Fronpage server extensions which I am not allowed to have on the server